# Lightning event force:navigateToObjectHome, pass filter criteria?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I code snippet similar to below.

*Question* Is it possible to pass filter field information to Object's Home page?

example: Instead of showing all the contact list, i wanted to filter by search string on name and only limited list of contacts will be displayed.

```
navHome : function (component, event, helper) {
    var homeEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToObjectHome");
    homeEvent.setParams({
        "scope": "Contact"
    });
    homeEvent.fire();
}
```